# random multigraph without self loops

Tags: networkx

How can I generate a random multidigraph in networkX with an exact degree sequence specified, but without self loops?

I am using the example:

https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/auto_examples/graph/plot_degree_sequence.html?highlight=degree%20sequence

Thanks,

Alvaro

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from networkx import nx

x = (1,1)
y = (1,1)
print(nx.is_graphical(x))

print("Configuration model")
G = nx.directed_configuration_model(x,y)  # configuration model
in_degree_sequence  = [d for n, d in G.in_degree()]  # degree sequence
out_degree_sequence = [d for n, d in G.out_degree()]
print("Degree sequence %s" % in_degree_sequence)
print("Degree histogram")
hist = {}
for d in in_degree_sequence:
    if d in hist:
        hist[d] += 1
    else:
        hist[d] = 1
print("degree #nodes")
for d in hist:
    print('%d %d' % (d, hist[d]))

nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far, and include the code for your attempts. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi, I tried this code.

Comment: This is hard.  How large do you need it to be?  And how random does it need to be?